# htaccess redirect files with no file extension and pass parameters to a file

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://abc.com/test/batch/profile/anyname

In the above url **anyname** varies depending upon the selected link.

I have to redirect the above url to friend.php  and I should pass anyname as parameter to that file

How can I do this?

Comment: Where exactly would `friend.php` be? I assume `http://abc.com/friend.php`?

Comment: friend.php is in the batch folder. profile is an appended string not folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9]+)$ friend.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

This allows that people access the following url on your site:

`http://www.yoursite.com/profile/abc`

`http://www.yoursite.com/profile/abc123`

`http://www.yoursite.com/profile/123`

However, any other characters than alphanumerics will not qualify for the rewrite above.

`Edit:`

If you actually will be keeping the `http://www.yoursite.com/test/batch/`-url, the `.htaccess` would have to be adjusted accordingly. I just assumed that you'd be using the root of `http://www.yoursite.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/batch/profile/([^/?]*)$ friend.php?param=$1
```